# Get Notified on List Item Changes - not using email

Tags: splistitem, alert, version-history, rss

I'm searching for an easy way to display the latest changes of a sharepoint list.

**Situation:** one huge list (10k entries) with a lot of daily changes (lets say 100).
**Target:** Display the changes during the day, e.g:
Item 122 was changed by userX
Field 1: old value -> new value
Field 2: old value -> new value

I've thought about a lot of ways, for example get the latests changed items using the caml webservice and then read the version history one by one...

My wish would be to get a notification (but not using mail, since this would require another email server of the changed items. It should not be necessary to deploy any code to the sharepoint, since its a production system.

Any possibility for additional notifications? Or an RSS feed that includes the changes on field level?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you think about an event receiver for updated, that populates a hidden list, which you make yourself an RSS feed for?

Comment: Is it possible to create an event reciever without c#/vb? how?

Comment: I'm taking that would be an issue for you? It is probably by far the easiest solution, you could put content expiry on the log list to, make it nice and tidy, but yes this would be a programmatic solution.

Comment: I'm searching for something "external" like an push of changes to an url. Or a possibility to get the latest changes with old values and new values in one step

Comment: Problem is, you can't get the version history easily, you can order by created, but you can't see WHAT was altered. If that's sufficient you could look at the Frontpage RPC and using that as a feed for the list?

Comment: what do you mean with Frontpage RPC?

Comment: "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={list-guid}&XMLDATA=TRUE" It's basically frontpage rpc from way back when

Comment: How to include the changed fields and values?

Comment: It would still need to be filtered, but there are plenty of web parts and applications that can do that. But you should see the versions in that feed. I can't think of another view where you see the versions.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and easy**

Here is one way:  http://spxsltws.codeplex.com/

You could add this web part then point it at the ListItemChanges function of /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx then use xsl transform to display it.

The basic idea is a web part that consumes a web service and returns results through xsl transform. I think this will be the most elegant solution. I was gonna write one, but the codeplex one looks really pretty good.

**More Control for more work**

Another solution would be to write a .net bdc that consumes the lists web service and turns it into an external list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a View with:

1. Sort by: Modified
2. Sort direction: Descending
3. Filter: Modified, is greater than, [Today]-1

Then to get the view's RSS feed. Edit the view, and next to "Web address of this view" click the RSS icon.

Comment: RSS does not include the changed field values (old and new value), or does it?

Comment: Nope. Sorry - missed that part. No field level changes. Getting field level changes efficiently, without writing server code isn't possible, AFAIK.